# Width of the div changes after reaching the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a blog site example I want to fix the position of the div after it reaches the top of the page. I am using materialize.css
This is my code

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col m8 s12">
     <!-- some content here -->
     </div>

    <div class="col s12 m4">
                    <div class="collection with-header" style="margin-top:3rem;">
                        <h5 class="collection-item">Trending topics</h5>
                        <a href="#" class="collection-item">Web design</a>
                        <a href="#" class="collection-item">Express framework</a>
                        <a href="#" class="collection-item">Cache API</a>
                        <a href="#" class="collection-item">Event handling in JavaScript</a>
                        <a href="#" class="collection-item">Django framework</a>
                    </div>

    <!-- This div should be fixed after reaching the top -->
                    <div class="card-panel center" id="post-author" style="width:auto">
                        <div class="follow-author">
                            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="" class="responsive-img circle"
                                style="width:75px;">
                            <div class="blue-text darken-3">Ishaan Sheikh</div>
                            <small class="grey-text">@sheikh_i</small>
                            <div class="divider" style="margin:1rem 0;"></div>
                            <div class="grey-text">Follow Author </div>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                         </div>
                    </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is the javascript code.

```
window.onscroll = function () {
            myFunction();
        };

        var header = document.getElementById("post-author");
        var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                header.classList.add("sticky");
            } else {
                header.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }
```

sticky class is defined as:

```
.sticky {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
        }
```

The problem is that the div get fixed but the `width of the div changes and it gets shrinked.`
I don't know why this is happening I am stuck with this from last 2 days.

You can see the example [Here](http://sigmalabs.xyz/example/test.html)

Comment: because you have width auto - give it the same widths as `s12` and `m4` classes so it will keep the width of the column

Comment: I added width:100%  to the sticky class but it is not working.

Comment: `position:fixed` removes the element form the normal flow of the document. And since it has `auto width`, its width changes. Give it a fixed width.

Comment: that's because 100% isn't the size of `m4` (that would only work on small screen as that equates to sm12).  If you are going to use a framework, learn how it works properly

Comment: it will not work. The `position: fixed` has to have specified `width` otherwise it will have always auto width.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the addition of `sticky` class that contains the `position: fixed;` attribute.

`fixed` effectively removes the div from the column thus, `width:auto` works differently now.

You need to redesign the columns using fixed widths

**EDIT**

**fixed**

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
>   created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
>   to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except
>   when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter
>   property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms
>   Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block.
>   (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and
>   filter contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position
>   is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left. This
>   value always creates a new stacking context. In printed documents, the
>   element is placed in the same position on every page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @Ishaan - Your columns have percentages as widths. But the problem is `position:fixed`. Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` removes the element form the normal flow of the document. And since it has auto width, its width changes. Give it a fixed width.

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 321px;
}
```

Read more here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: that's not a snippet. did you mean to add a code sample?

Comment: I agree with @johnny04501. The columns all have percentages as widths. If you resize the window the columns will change width but `.sticky` won't

Comment: @johnny04501 I agree with you both. I do not think that he intends to keep the sticky element at the top on small size screen. (: